# I'm having trouble figuring out the difference between these two blocks of code

Tags: c

Alright, this is a really quick question: why does this first block of code compile, but the second one doesn't? They seem like they should be equivalent, since all that I change is the variable declaration/references.

First:

```
int memberStudents(struct studentType x, Snodeptr students, Snodeptr *s) {
    Snodeptr p = *s;

    while (p->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(x.sid, p->student.sid) == 0)
            return 1;

        p = p->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Second:

```
int memberStudents(struct studentType x, Snodeptr students, Snodeptr *s) {
    while (s->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(x.sid, s->student.sid) == 0)
            return 1;

            s = s->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to change the Snodeptr s so that it points to the proper place, but when I try the second block of code I get an error saying there is a request for member 'next' in something not a struct or union.

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `Snodeptr`? I'm guessing it's a typedef'ed pointer to something and then `Snodeptr s` is what you want, not `Snodeptr *s`

Comment: Please include the definition of your structures.

Comment: They both will crash if the argument s happens to be NULL. The first one will also crash if *s is NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Snodeptr *s` and `Snodeptr p` are different types, and therefore behave differently

try `(*s)->next`

Comment: Oh, alright I got it working. I was using just *s->next, which I didn't know was syntactically different than (*s)->next. Thanks; it's working now.

Comment: @user1883424: postfix operators such as `->` have higher precedence than unary operators like `*`, so `*s->next` parses as `*(s->next)`; you're dereferencing the result of `s->next`, which is not what you want.  `(*s)->next` forces `s` to be dereferenced before applying the `->` operator to the result.

Answer (score 2):

In the first block, the `while` loop operates on a `Snodeptr` instance.  In the second block you're operating on a `Snodeptr*`.

Comment: I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to edit the Snodeptr s that is passed to memberStudents if I can only operate on a new instance of it.

Comment: Ignore my previous answer, you're correct that you need to get the second code block working.  Sam I am's suggestion is correct here

Answer (score 1):

In the second code, you are using `s->next != NULL`, s is pointer.

In the first code, you are using `p->next != NULL`, p is not pointer

Answer (score 1):

I expect this (slightly modified version of your second snippet) should compile:

```
int memberStudents(struct studentType x, Snodeptr students, Snodeptr *s) {
    while ((*s)->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(x.sid, (*s)->student.sid) == 0)
            return 1;

            (*s) = (*s)->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the final `(*s) = (*s)->next;` should be `s = &(*s)->next;`

Comment: Yeah, I got it working using that method. I didn't know that the parenthesis were necessary. Thanks

Comment: The answer by @ Happy Green X mutilates the linked list. To avoid that you'll need my ampersand version. NB: the parentheses are needed because "->" binds tighter than "*"